# Not able to set priority in RMQ in java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using amqp client 5.5.1 in my java code. I have declare Queue using priority argument:

```
RMQMessageHandler.declareQueue()---> method

Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("x-max-priority", 10);
        channel.queueDeclare(rmqQueueName, true, false, false, args);
```

And added consumer to consume queue messages:

```
public void consumeBrokerMessage(final String rmqQueueName) throws IOException {

    declareQueue(rmqQueueName);
    log.info(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    final Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(
                final String consumerTag,
                final Envelope envelope,
                final AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                final byte[] body) throws IOException {
            boolean flag = false;
            final String brokerMessage = new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
           if (null != properties.getPriority()) {
                //setting value in pojo object
            } else {
                //setting 0 value in pojo object
            }
            //logic

            final long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
            // positively acknowledge a single delivery, the message will
            // be discarded
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        }
    };
    channel.basicQos(1);
    channel.basicConsume(rmqQueueName, false, consumer);
}
```

When I am running my code, but I am getting below exception:

```
java.io.IOException: null
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:962)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclare(AutorecoveringChannel.java:333)
at com.springernature.acdc.transformation.rmq.RMQMessageHandler.declareQueue(RMQMessageHandler.java:103)
at com.springernature.acdc.transformation.rmq.RMQMessageHandler.consumeBrokerMessage(RMQMessageHandler.java:49)
at com.springernature.acdc.transformation.ACDCTransformationEngine.start(ACDCTransformationEngine.java:28)
at com.springernature.acdc.transformation.ACDCTransformationMain.main(ACDCTransformationMain.java:17)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'acdc-transformation' in vhost '736e9777-65f3-499d-a94e-abc9e3b91135': received the value '10' of type 'signedint' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:499)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:292)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'acdc-transformation' in vhost '736e9777-65f3-499d-a94e-abc9e3b91135': received the value '10' of type 'signedint' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:516)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:672)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:599)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could you please let me know, where am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: You did not tell us, where (in which line) the exception occurs. In fact, you did not post the whole error message, which includes a stacktrace. But as far as I can see, "channel is already closed" seems to be self-explanatory.

Comment: I have updated with error message.

Comment: This is a completely other error message ?!?

Comment: you already have this queue declared, but without 'x-max-priority' property

Comment: @user1516873, Yes It was in my Junit test cases, and its working fine once I have added 'x-max-priority' property as well in JUnit test case. Thank you for you r comment.